# Restore ubuntu server from factory from ssh

Tags: 20.04

Is it possible to factory reset ubuntu server 20.04 from SSH?

I would need to do it so I don't have to go to where I have the server physically and save me the trip.

Comment: Ubuntu does not have any way to factory reset. You would have to reinstall.

Comment: It depends. On package level you can purge any set of packages.